# UITableView - adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth in sectionHeader

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I've created a custom `sectionHeader` for my `UITableview`.

Sometimes I have to fill it with large text, so I added `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` which normally works.

In this case the font is not resized when it is to large. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width:
        tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))
    headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    headerLabel.text = self.tableView(self.tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)
    headerLabel.sizeToFit()
    headerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    headerLabel.clipsToBounds=true
    headerLabel.numberOfLines=0
    headerLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail
    headerLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.4
    headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)

    return headerView
}
```

Comment: can you try by removing headerLabel.sizeToFit()?

Comment: Worked for me thanks.

Comment: great, putting as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove

**headerLabel.sizeToFit()** to make **adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth** property working.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to delete this line:

```
headerLabel.sizeToFit()
```